# How to show number of selected item in CAB

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to figure out how to show number of selected list items in my CAB(Contextual Action Bar),for example when I long pressed one list item I would see "1 selected item" in my CAB,and when I long pressed 2 items,I would see "2 selected item" in my CAB and so on, Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Call `setSubtitle()` when the selection changes, adjusting it to the new count. If you are using a `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` `ListView`, you can override `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` on your `MultiChoiceModeListener` to find out when to call `setSubtitle()`.

Comment: it's working but with a little change,actionmode.setTitle(String.valueOf(numberOfCheckedItems)  + " " + getString(R.string.sub_title_fav)); ,thank's alot ;)